# How can i get solrclient, solr endpointurl and index used by hybris facet search?

Tags: java, solr, sap-commerce-cloud, faceted-search

I has my SAP Hybris project in JAVA. It using solr for caching product and other data.
I want to search data from the solr with specified string and relevance product of string.
I achieved it by using hybris faceted search classes. But it is very slow in nature.
So i created my HttpSorlClient and form query by myself, and it is tacking very less time.

```
final String urlString = "https://localhost:8983/solr/indexName";
final HttpSolrClient httpSolrClient = new HttpSolrClient.Builder(urlString).build();
final SolrQuery solrQuery = new SolrQuery();

final StringBuffer queryString = new StringBuffer();
        final String[] terms = searchtext.split(" ");
        IntStream.range(0, terms.length).forEach(idx -> {
            queryString.append("((code_string:");
            queryString.append(terms[idx] + "~) OR ");

            if (idx < terms.length - 1)
            {
                queryString.append(" OR ");
            }
        });

        solrQuery.set("q", queryString.toString());
        solrQuery.setFields("name_text_en");
        solrQuery.setRows(10000);

        final QueryRequest queryRequest = new QueryRequest(solrQuery);
            queryRequest.setBasicAuthCredentials("solrserver", "server123");
            final QueryResponse solrResponse = queryRequest.process(httpSolrClient);
            final SolrDocumentList documentList = solrResponse.getResults();
```

Here i want my urlString which is used by Hybris facet searching. If anyone has idea about it please suggest.

Comment: So you want to use Solr Server as external system and integrate with Server Client approach. And you don't want to use OOTB Facet Search Service, is this correct?

Comment: yes i want to execute my own created query . like  This                                                    
 final QueryRequest queryRequest = new QueryRequest(solrQuery);     QueryResponse solrResponse = queryRequest.process(httpSolrClient);

Comment: Am I not sure what problem you are facing? are you not able to send the request? not able to generate the query? or not able to process the response?

Comment: hello @ZaheerAttar thanks for reply. Above code is working fine but i want to use classes of hybris faceted search. And i has resolved it now. Thanks for reply.